# Kubernetes and Docker - Running single core application

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

### Background

I have Google cloud Kubernetes which running my application from Docker image. My nodes pool are machines with 8 CPUs.

### The Problem

One of my applications are not using the CPUs well because it's written with Python (read more about python Global Interpreter Lock - GIL - problem).

So, the enviroment is running with 8 core but the application don't need it.

### The Question

Is this possible to decide how many cores my application will "see"? I want to limit it to "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’ll read [this documentation from Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#specify-a-cpu-request-and-a-cpu-limit), you’ll see that resource management is “baked in” to Kubernetes, specially for defining both the number of CPUs allocated and how much each CPU is used.

This is defined in a .yaml file.

From the documentation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cpu-demo
  namespace: cpu-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: cpu-demo-ctr
    image: vish/stress
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        cpu: "0.5"
    args:
    - -cpus
    - "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `request` and the `limit` of the resources for a specific pod.

```
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        cpu: "0.5"
```

Read more about it: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/